# Filling field with automatic numbering specific by unique value of another field using QGIS expression

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, qgsexpression

I have a table with two fields: `"NUMBER"` (integer) and `"TOWN"` (text).
I would like to find an expression that fills the `"NUMBER"` field with an automatic number specific for each value of `"TOWN"`.

Example:

```
NUMBER | TOWN
----------------------
1      | STRASBOURG
2      | STRASBOURG
3      | STRASBOURG
1      | PARIS
2      | PARIS
1      | TOULOUSE
2      | TOULOUSE
3      | TOULOUSE
4      | TOULOUSE
```

How can I do that with a QGIS expression?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7):

Finally, I found the right expression to do that:

```
"TOWN" || (@row_number - minimum(@row_number, "TOWN") + 1)
```